# How to get Data in List in Ionic hybrid application

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am beginner in Ionic hybrid development.I want to parse data in List in my project.
I am using this webservice:http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=bertt.
I want to show all dates in List.This is json Responce

`{
    "earthquakes": [
        {
            "datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
            "depth": 24.4,
            "lng": 142.369,
            "src": "us",
            "eqid": "c0001xgp",
            "magnitude": 8.8,
            "lat": 38.322
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2012-04-11 06:38:37",
            "depth": 22.9,
            "lng": 93.0632,
            "src": "us",
            "eqid": "c000905e",
            "magnitude": 8.6,
            "lat": 2.311
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2007-09-12 09:10:26",
            "depth": 30,
            "lng": 101.3815,
            "src": "us",
            "eqid": "2007hear",
            "magnitude": 8.4,
            "lat": -4.5172
        }]}`

Please suggest the tutorial or post some code its really help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need data provider **earthquakes-provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EarthquakesProvider {

  constructor(public _http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Earthquakes Provider');
  }

  loadEarthquakes(){
    return this._http.get('http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=bertt')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Second, you need page that will display your JSON data for example in **home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EarthquakesProvider } from '../../providers/earthquakes-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [EarthquakesProvider]
})
export class HomePage {

  public DateList: Array<Object>;

  constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController,
              public _earthquakes: EarthquakesProvider ) {

       this.getEarthquakes();

  }

  getEarthquakes(){
     this._earthquakes.loadEarthquakes().subscribe(res => {
     this.DateList = res.earthquakes;
     console.log(res.earthquakes);
    });
  }

}
```

And finally **home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Show dates in List</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content-background">

<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of DateList">
    {{ item.datetime }}
  </button>  
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

P.S. You can use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) to parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times

Comment: sir i am getting this error "Error: No provider for Http!" @Tomislav Stankovic